# Bootstrap: Using nav beside a floated element pushes other content down

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a 2 column layout with a bootstrap nav in the right column.  The problem is that content in the right column should sit immediately below the nav, but instead is pushed down to clear the left column.  The result is that my right column has a nav, then lots of vertical white space, then the content.

Here's the code:

```
<head>
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style>
        .left-column {
            padding: 10px;
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            float: left;
        }
        .right-column {
            padding: 10px;
            color: red;
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin-left: 320px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="left-column">
    <p>This is the left content</p>
</div>

<div class="right-column">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p>This is the right content</p>
</div>

</body>
```

The reason that the right content is pushed down is that the left column is floated, and bootstrap navs have an `:after` pseudo element with the rule `clear: both;`.

I have tried to find a way to do the 2 column layout without floating the left, but I need the right to take up the remaining horizontal space, and this is the only way I could do it.

I also tried:

- removing the `clear: both;` rule, but I end up with the right content appended horizontally on to the nav
- adding other pseudo elements after the nav
- containing the nav in a floated block, per the notes on this mozilla page, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You could make the left column positioned absolutely? Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/zc7e2Lt1/1/ (edited with the correct link)

Comment: Nice idea Joshhunt.  Works with the example above.  In my real code though I have a container (with a background colour) that wraps both columns.  Absolute positioning the left column takes it out of the document flow, so that it overflows the container when it is longer than the right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules for floats apply to items within the same block formatting context.  There are several ways to create a new block formatting context, per this article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context.  The option that worked best for me was to set the `overflow` property of the right column to `auto`.  There is a good explanation here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow.